# Number palindrome code not working

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm working my way through Project Euler, and on problem 4 my palindrome code isn't working. Specifically, it returns 998001 (999*999) as if it were a palindrome.

The code to check the palindrome works, but it keeps looping and replacing the max value despite it not being a palindrome. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help

```
public int palindromeNumber()
{
    int max=0;
    for(int x = 100; x<1000; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 100; y<1000; y++)
        {
            int z = x*y;
            StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(z));
            StringBuilder rev = num.reverse();
            if(num==rev)
            {
                max=z;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: use .equals() to compare strings

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look on the StringBuilder.reverse() method it returns the reference to the same object (num in your case)

```
@Override
public StringBuilder reverse() {
    super.reverse();
    return this;
}
```

So you rev == num is always true and you get the 999*999 because it is the end of a loop

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct, however, as the comments have pointed out, you are comparing addresses instead of strings.

A String is an object, not a primitive type, so `'=='` will not work when you compare original and reversed.

Instead, you need to use the `.equals(String)` method.

Here's a one-liner proof of concept:

```
max = (num.equals(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(z)).reverse())) ? z : max;
```

**Note:**

For performance reasons, you might wanna try to implement this numerically, conversions and parsing take time.

Quick proof of concept:

```
 num = origNum
 while (num > 0)
 {
      digit = num % 10;
      rev = rev * 10 + digit;
      num = num / 10;
 }

 if (origNum == rev) //max..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please make some changes as - 

public static int palindromeNumber()
{
    int max=0;
    for(int x = 100; x<1000; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 100; y<1000; y++)
        {
            int z = x*y;
            StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(z));
            StringBuilder numberCopy = new StringBuilder(num);
            StringBuilder rev = num.reverse();

            if(numberCopy.toString().equals(rev.toString()))
            {
                max=z;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

The problem in your code is that , when you use  rev = num.reverse();
Then each time in loop It modify the same object- num with reversed number and then assign it to rev. Now both reference- num & rev pointing to the same modified object.(num and rev value is 999 in last iteration)

Then you are using == which check reference are pointing to the same object or not, and here num and rev points to same object so condition is true every time.

Solution -

1. copy object to another object before modifying which can be used later for comparison.
2. use equals to compare values instead ==.

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, you should [edit] it to explain how it works and how is it different from what the asker has tried.

Comment: @dorukayhan Thank you for suggestion. Edited answer.

Comment: I changed it to this, but now I get 580085.

Comment: Got it to work. Created a List for the palindromes and got the max from there. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @cuttlefish Welcome